# iOS - Get Header Results

Tags: objective-c, ios

A quick question. I have the following code which gets the mod date of a file on a server:

```
- (void) sendRequestForLastModifiedHeaders
{
    /*  send a request for file modification date  */
    NSURLRequest *modReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLInput.text]
                                        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0f];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:modReq delegate:self];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
{
    /*  convert response into an NSHTTPURLResponse, 
    call the allHeaderFields property, then get the
    Last-Modified key.
    */

    NSHTTPURLResponse *foo = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields];

    NSString * last_modified = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                            [[(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields] objectForKey:@"Last-Modified"]];

    NSLog(@"Last-Modified: %@", last_modified );

}
```

My main question is the following:

Does this call only send over the header? If the file is big I do not want the whole file being downloaded. That is why I'm checking the header.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
After the update this works...
Thanks now looks like:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *modReq = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:               URLInput.text]
                                        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0f];   
[modReq setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];
```

Comment: Are you checking for last modified headers just to find out whether you need to download a new copy of a file? If so, I would recommend using a premade HTTP request library with all of this built in, like [`ASIHTTPRequest`](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest). The various cache policies you can set there should be suitable for your situation.

Comment: For more than you ever wanted to know about how HTTP works, take a look through [RFC 2616](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616).  Section 9 defines the various methods GET, HEAD, POST, etc.  The methods other than those three are seldom used.

Comment: @iOSGuy are you on twitter?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As you have it now, you're probably downloading the whole file. The key is the http method used for the http request.  By default, it's a GET request.  What you want is a HEAD request.  You don't want the file, you just want the server to return the response that you would get if you did, right?

To do that, you want to use a `NSMutableURLRequest` and `setHTTPMethod:` to construct a request with a method of HEAD, instead of GET.