# IOS - How to handle return calls from a RESTful service API

Tags: html, objective-c, ios, api, submit

I am using an API to have users create an account within my app.

Now I am able to generate the URL required in objective-C to submit the values and in the API documentation it has the return numbers that will confirm to me what has happened.

My question is how do I relay that information to the user of the app?
The return call is shown to me in a HTML page as plain text.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

///////

> 2012-10-03 12:24:31.557 Multi Web[72631:15203] Dictionary list - {
>       Connection = "keep-alive";
>       "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
>       "Content-Length" = 26;
>       "Content-Location" = "signup.php";
>       "Content-Type" = "text/html";
>       Date = "Tue, 02 Oct 2012 23:24:32 GMT";
>       P3P = "policyref=\"/w3c/p3p.xml\", CP=\"ALL CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND UNI COM NAV INT STA PRE\"";
>       Server = "Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)";
>       Status = "200 OK";
>       TCN = choice;
>       Vary = "negotiate,Accept-Encoding";
>       "X-Limit-Key-Limit" = 10000;
>       "X-Limit-Key-Remaining" = 9992;
>       "X-Limit-Key-Reset" = 236;
>       "X-Limit-User-Limit" = 320;
>       "X-Limit-User-Remaining" = 319;
>       "X-Limit-User-Reset" = 3600;
>       "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.14";

I got this in my console so I now, I have created the account succesfully.
In the middle it says Status = "200 OK";

How do I use that particular line? If I can hook up a UIAlertView to that then i am where I want to be.

Cheers.

Comment: I don't understand this last part: "The return call is shown to me in a HTML page as plain text.?" Are you submitting an HTTP request and seen a text/plain response that includes the result code?

Comment: yes, so if I put the URL in a browser, I will see the result of the url in a browser and then if I check the source code, there is no formatting.

Comment: Is it XML, JSON, plain text? I'm guessing you are using a `NSURLRequest`?

Comment: Nope was not using that yet - maybe I should look into that. and it is plain text as far as I can tell

Comment: Also which API are you calling?

Comment: its a login form from getPocket.com - to save websites from a UIWebView to the Pocket web Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if your situation is related to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251448/ios-get-header-results) According to docs from the [getPocket API](http://getpocket.com/api/docs/#api) you are using, i see the following:

[image]

According to [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html), the default HTTP method is GET. What you need to do is check the response headers from the API. So what you need to do is change your httpMethod to HEAD like so:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *modReq = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.somesite.com/?something"]];
    [modReq setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];
```

Then you can read the values from the header with something like so:

```
NSURLResponse* response = // the response, from somewhere
NSDictionary* headers = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields];
```

You can then get the response values, and tell the user whats up accordingly.

Comment: I have added a bit of my console log, when you wrote @"HEAD" is that relevant to the status I am after??

Comment: That console log you have printed. Is that from the response HEAD ?

Comment: There ya go ;) .. If it is from the response head, then it is a dictionary. The status key should have the response you need.

Answer (score 0):

It's called designing and creating a user interface.

You send a request to the server and get a response. Your job is to examine the response, recognise what it means, and tell the user in an appropriate way what the response meant. Since the user is not an expert in parsing html, showing the html would almost always be entirely inappropriate.

For a user entering a username and password correctly, the appropriate response is usually that the user can now access the site.